# VBA to save current file into a file on SharePoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

My current macro cuts certain pages from a document. My goal is for these pages to then be saved into another word document in SharePoint. I've set up the directory below. The sharepoint link is taken directory from the word doc I wish to save in. I'm successful in saving these pages into sharepoint, but need to save them into another word doc on sharepoint. The name of the doc I wish to save it in on sharepoint is roster.docx. The link is it's directory.

```
Sub CopyPages()
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim rCurrent As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iEnd As Integer

    Set rCurrent = Selection.Range

    ' Get page numbers to be copied
    sTemp = InputBox("Page range to copy (use format 6-7)", "")
    i = InStr(sTemp, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        iStart = Val(Left(sTemp, i - 1))
        iEnd = Val(Mid(sTemp, i + 1))

        If iStart < 1 Then iStart = 1
        If iEnd < iStart Then iEnd = iStart
        With ActiveDocument.Range
            If iStart > .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
                iStart = .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
            End If
            If iEnd > .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
                iEnd = .Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
            End If
        End With

        ' Set the range
        Set rCopy = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, _
          Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=iStart)

        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, _
          Count:=iEnd
        rCopy.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End

        ' Copy range to a new document
        rCopy.Copy
        Documents.Add
        ActiveDocument.Range.PasteSpecial
        'Selecting a location where you want your selection to save
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="https://xyz.sharepoint.com/pm/TSCR/TSCR%20Home%20Pages%20PM%20Documentation/Portal%20Designer/roster.docx?d=wb7d91e510f3544a5a2e4a0d549cdeab9"
        rCurrent.Select
    Else
        If sTemp > "" Then
            MsgBox "There is no dash character"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: So when I run the macro, my page selection separates as a new doc, but I want that selection to save into a document that is on share point. As of now, it just pastes as a new document on share point, but does not actually paste inside my selected document on sharepoint. The link I have references to the  document I want my selection to be saved in

Comment: So you need to write code to open the target document, determine where you want the copied info to be pasted and then paste.

Comment: Having problems with this...do you have any sample code I can reference?

Comment: Use the macro recorder to get you started. You will see what steps Excel would take. You are looking for the objects used and the syntax, not the way to write it. The macro recorder is goods for discovery, but a horrible example of how to write good code.